# Getting Error as getEditor undefined

Tags: extjs, combobox

I'm trying to get the value of a cell in a grid using below. In-fact I'm just trying to print it in the console

```
console.log(Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridcolumn[itemId=gridId]')[0].getEditor().getStore().findRecord('description', 'Description'));
```

**Grid Code**

```
Ext.define('Examples.grid.fdGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    xtype: foodGrid',
    forceNewStore: true,
    itemId: 'foodGrid',
    height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height - 200,
    autoload: false,
    columns: [
    {
            text: 'Food Distrib',
            xtype: 'gridcolumn',
            itemId:'gridId', 
            dataIndex: 'food_distributor',
            flex: 1,
            renderer: function(value){
            if(Ext.isNumber(value)){
                var store = this.getEditor().getStore();
                return store.findRecord('foodid',value).get('description');
            }
            return value;
            },
            editor: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                allowBlank: true,
                displayField: "description",
                valueField: "foodid",                      
                listeners: {

                    expand: function () {
                        var call = this.up('foodgrid[itemId=foodGrid]').getSelectionModel().selection.record.data.networkname.trim();
                        this.store.clearFilter();
                        this.store.filter({
                            property: 'call',
                            value: call,
                            exactMatch: true
                        })
                    }
                },

            },
        }
        });
```

But i'm getting an error as `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined`

What's the error please?

Added the Grid Code part, and the column whose value I want to print.

Comment: Can you share your grid code? `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('gridcolumn[itemId=foodDistrib]')[0]` is returning undefined. Your query is incorrect.

Comment: I think if it doesnt support getEditor() try to use this.editor object

Comment: You are using `itemId=foodDistrib` but I am not seeing such ID anywhere, you should use `('#gridId')` , you have this Id in your column.

Comment: @pagep

`Error: "Ext.data.Model#persistenceProperty" is deprecated.`
    `at new Ext.Error (http://localhost:3000/scripts/ext-classic/ext-all-debug.js:2555:21)`
    `at Function.raise (http://localhost:3000/scripts/ext-classic/ext-all-debug.js:2614:23)`
    `at Object.Ext.raise (http://localhost:3000/scripts/ext-classic/ext-all-debug.js:2693:21)`
    `at constructor.get (http://localhost:3000/scripts/ext-classic/ext-all-debug.js:11083:29)`
    `at constructor.remoteFunction (<anonymous>:2:14)`

Answer (score 0):

The editor is created when needed (when the first edit occurs). So when the renderer is first called, the editor is not yet available.

What you want to do from inside your renderer, is to directly access the store, not go through the editor. Then you only need a pre-loaded store to be able to render the grid correctly.

```
    renderer: function(value){
        if(Ext.isNumber(value)){
            var store =Ext.getStore("MyStore");
            return store.findRecord('foodid',value).get('description');
        }
        return value;
    },
    editor: {
        xtype:'combobox',
        store:'MyStore'
```

Of course, you have to make sure that `MyStore` is loaded before you render the grid.

Comment: But I'm loading the store remotely, I don't have to create it here  right??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have

```
var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
              clicksToEdit: 1
});
```

Without the plugin the editor doesnt work! and the editor will be undefined when you will try to obtain it

Answer (score 0):

One can only guess what you are trying to do there but:

- `Column` doesn't have a selection model of itself. `Grid` does.
- `Combobox` needs a store.
- `getEditor` may return `String` OR `Object` if an editor was set and column is `editable`
- `editable` is provided by a grid plugin. In other words, specifying a column as being editable and specifying a column editor will not be enough, you also need to provide the grid with the editable plugin.

Some working example:

```
Ext.define('Examples.grid.fdGrid', {
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

xtype: 'feedGrid',
forceNewStore: true,
itemId: 'foodGrid',
height: Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height - 200,
autoload: false,
 selModel: 'cellmodel',
plugins: {
    ptype: 'cellediting',
    clicksToEdit: 1
},
columns: [
{
        text: 'Food Distrib',
        xtype: 'gridcolumn',
        itemId:'gridId', 
        dataIndex: 'food_distributor',
        flex: 1,
        editable: true,
        renderer: function(value){
        if(Ext.isNumber(value)){
            var store = this.getEditor().getStore();
            return store.findRecord('foodid',value).get('description');
        }
        return value;
        },

        editor: {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            allowBlank: true,
            displayField: "description",
            valueField: "foodid",    
            store: {
                fields:['food_distributor', 'description'],
                data:[
                    {
                        'food_distributor':'a',
                        foodid:1,
                        description:'aaaaa'
                    },
                    {
                        'food_distributor':'a',
                        foodid:2,
                        description:'bbbbbb'
                    },
                    {
                        'food_distributor':'a',
                        foodid:3,
                        description:'aaaaa'
                    }]
            },
            listeners: {
                expand: function () {
                    debugger;
                    var desc = this.up('grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0].get('description').trim();
                    this.store.clearFilter();
                    this.store.filter({
                        property: 'description',
                        value: desc,
                        exactMatch: true
                    })
                }
            },

        },
    }
    ]
});

Ext.create('Examples.grid.fdGrid', {
    store: {
        fields:['food_distributor', 'description'],
        data:[
            {
                'food_distributor':'a',
                foodid:1,
                description:'aaaaa'
            },
            {
                'food_distributor':'a',
                foodid:2,
                description:'bbbbbb'
            },
            {
                'food_distributor':'a',
                foodid:3,
                description:'aaaaa'
            }]
    },
    renderTo:Ext.getBody()
})
```